# Why are certain hexadecimal escape characters not displayed in python 3 unless the print statement is used?

Tags: python

I am learning about strings and bytestrings in python. I don't understand why certain hexadecimal escape sequences are displayed in \XNN form and some are not?

```python
s = 'A\x31\tC'
s1 = 'A\x00B\tC'
```

In this case, when I type s1 into the console, it prints the exact string of characters within the quotes,'A\x00B\tC', but when I type s into the console, it prints 'A1B\tC'. It is only when I print s1 that the screen shows 'AB       C'. I don't understand why certain escape characters are shown and others are not? And why does it then show when you print them?

Cheers

Comment: But you do not seem to be as surprised that the sequence `\t` does not get printed as such either.

Comment: I believe you have a mistake in your question. `s1` could never output `'A1B\tC'`, with `print` or otherwise. It doesn't contain the `1` character; `s` does, though.

Comment: @usr2564301 I realised after I posted that this was indeed something that I was also unsure of, but I figured that an answer to the question would answer that as well!

Comment: @jpmc26 thanks for that, I believe I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://www.asciitable.com/

If you look at the ASCII table, you would see that some characters are printable, while others are not.

In particular, `\x31` == `1` (Hexadecimal 31 == Decimal 49 == ASCII Character `1`.

On the other hand `\x00` is not printable. It represents the null terminator (or `\0`)

```
>>> '\x31' == '1'
True
>>> '\x00' == '\0'
True
```

A more interesting question is: Why does `\x31` get converted to `1`, `\x09` gets converted to a `\t`, while `\x00` is not converted to `\0`. That I don't know.

Comment: This makes sense to me, thank you for this. As for your last comment, I'm not sure how much this helps but this link gave the general overview for how the concept of encoding works at least: https://www.dotnetnoob.com/2011/12/introduction-to-character-encoding.html

Answer (score 2):

When you type name into the interpreter, it is using the result of calling [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) on that name. Since `\x31` can be represented as `1`, it uses that. Since `\x00` cannot be represented as a printable character, it falls back to using the hex escape notation.

Note that:

```
>>> '\x31' == '1'
True
```

So the result of `repr` is valid.

Comment: @usr2564301 Since passing the string to `print` results in *different* output on the terminal, `repr` behavior is actually a very good bet.

Comment: `repr` or `repr`-like behaviour was my understanding of how this worked, but I could be wrong.

Comment: So is the value from calling repr determined by the encoding system? Or is it predefined by python itself?